# Diagnostic output in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I learned programming in imperative languages, mostly C++ and C, so the functional approach is very new to me.

When I was writing functions/methods before, I usually took an 'incremental' approach (as probably most people do): writing some small part of the code, then checking if the results so far are as expected (usually by just printing them to stdout with printf or std::cout), refining the algorithm, enhancing the algorithm, then checking if the results so far are as expected (usually by just printing them to stdout with printf or std::cout), refining the… I very seldom wrote whole methods in one piece.

Essential to this 'incremental' approach is the ability to have diagnostic output (printf or std::cout in my example above). But in Haskell (as far as I understand as of now), I'd have to change the signature of my function if I want to - say - use 'putStrLn' to write something to stdout, because 'putStrLn' only returns an IO Monad that contains the information that I want printed, but does not print it in the moment of invoking 'putStrLn', right? So every time I want to use 'putStrLn' for diagnostic output, I'd have to change the signature of the current function and the way all my other functions call it etc…

So is there a cheap and easy way to print the value of a 'local variable' of a function to the standard output?

Or is the mere fact that I'm asking for that a sign that I'm not understanding a fundamental part of programming in Haskell?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is weird, because I find without a Read Eval Print Loop (REPL) in the languages you're used to, I'm forever frustrated by how much work it is to test my code as I go along. The REPL is fundamental to my incremental code development; you can use it to test your code *without* having to add a bunch of print statements.

- Have GHCi open at the same time as your editor.
- Write smaller, single-purpose functions. This seems bizzare at first, but function application is the basic unit of work in Haskell and doesn't have the sort of overheads you get in imperative languages.
- Each time you write a function, do `:r` in GHCi and test it with a variety of input.
- Haskell is very dense, so what counts as worth making into a separate function is much shorter on the screen than you're used to.

Occasionally you end up stuck in a lengthy monadic computation or something.  GHCi lets you set breakpoints - use these in preference to adding print statements to the code because you can mess about and investigate a bit more without editing code, and most importantly, you don't need to add Show constraints on your type signatures.

When you're done, you can manually inline gratuitously short helper functions and compile with `ghc -O2`.

(Using manually added print statements, or `Debug.Trace` module is a complete pain compared to this in my experience.)

**Summary**: Whenever possible, avoid editing your code while testing it. Use GHCi a lot.

Answer (score 13):

There is no good way to do what you want. You can get close with `Debug.Trace` but I don't recommend that while learning because of Haskell's non standard evaluation order.  Haskell does not work by sequentially setting the value of "variables" in the way languages like C and C++ do.  Because it is lazy, Haskell expressions are evaluated in an order that depends on use, so the incremental value thing does not really work.

Haskell is an *expression oriented language*.  Use that to your advantage:

1. Write short functions.  It is easier to see what each function does this way.  Most functions should be one line per equation, and real "one liners" should be common.
2. Use the REPL.  You should constantly be experimenting with your code in GHCi
3. Use the type system.  Haskell's type system is orders of magnitude more useful than the type systems in most imperative languages.  Types document intent in a machine checked way.  You can't expect to understand code without understanding the types.  When writing code, once you get the types right you are most of the way done.

Combine the above suggestions.  You can get the type for an expression in GHCi with `:t`.

Comment: But doesn't that mean that I'll have many functions and hence the namespace will be full with functions? Because defining many helper functions locally in a function makes them inaccessible from the outside and hence hard to experiment with... Also, finding meaningful function names for such many functions will be more difficult, and I see the trend in Haskell to keep function names short... This all confuses me :) In C++ for example, one tries to keep as much 'local' and encapsulates as possible...

Comment: In Haskell we use modules and export lists for encapsulation. Finding meaningful names for functions isn't more difficult than finding names for local variables with a bit of practice. I think the trend in Haskell is just to keep often used function names short. I often have long descriptive names for module internal functions that are used only a few times `boundedValueBlockTraversal` being an example in the code I'm currently working on. I also tend to fully document those functions, which results in very readable and maintainance friendly code.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to quickly add impure debugging output to a pure function using the `trace` function of the [Debug.Trace](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Debug-Trace.html) module. It is a function that returns its second argument with the additional side effect of printing the first argument when the second argument/returned value is forced.

I think it is totally acceptable to temporarily use this for debugging as long as it doesn't end up in any final commits or other permanent code. Also the order in which messages are printed matches the evaluation order which is also useful for debugging but not always the preferred order for the output.

If you need to use this very often it could also be a sign that you need to factor your code into smaller functions which makes it easier to inspect their behavior by just specifying arguments and looking at the return value.

Answer (score 1):

First, you can debug your functions by loading them into `ghci` and playing with them there.

Then, you can use `trace` from [`Debug.Trace`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Debug-Trace.html) to print a string when an expression is evaluated. However be aware that since Haskell uses lazy evaluation, in most cases an expression will be evaluated at a different time than you'd expect. See also [Wikibooks](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Debugging) and [Haskell wiki](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Debugging#Printf_and_friends). (Internally `trace` uses unsafe calls that allow it to print output even within pure code. Normally you're not supposed to use them, but in this particular case it is OK.)

Comment: To be more explicit, "this particular case" is development. `Debug.Trace` has no place in production code.

Answer (score 0):

There is a fairly short example [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Practical_monads#Generic_monads) of how to construct something that seems similar to what you describe. If I am reading it correctly, the author creates a simple monad that allows you to print out in the middle of computations, so to speak.

Answer (score 0):

Approximation:

1. GHCi debugging is the way to print local variables without cluttering your code.
2. A WriterT monad transformer, either strict or lazy, can serialize your logs if you return your traced value, paired with the result.

```
{-# LANGUAGE PackageImports #-}
-- import qualified "transformers" Control.Monad.Trans.Writer.Strict as W
import qualified "transformers" Control.Monad.Trans.Writer.Lazy as W

compute:: Int -> Int -> (Int, Int)
compute x y = (result, local)
  where
    local = 2 * x
    result = local + y

test :: (Monad m) => W.WriterT String m Int
test = do
  let (r1, local1) = compute 5 3
  W.tell $ "local1= " ++ show local1 ++ "\n"

  let (r2, local2) = compute 2 2
  W.tell $ "local2= " ++ show local2 ++ "\n"

  return $ r1 + r2

main = do
  (r, logs) <- W.runWriterT test
  putStrLn logs
  putStrLn $ "result= " ++ show r
```

outputs:

```
local1= 10
local2= 4

result= ...
```